# ImportError: cannot import name 'OnehotTransactions' from 'mlxtend.preprocessing'

Tags: python

Am studying Associations :
a) ImportError: cannot import name 'OnehotTransactions' from 'mlxtend.preprocessing'
(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlxtend\preprocessing_*init*_.py)

Answer (score 1):

As per the changelog the **OnehotTransactions** function is removed in favour of **TransactionEncoder**. More details [here](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/CHANGELOG/)

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue solved by `pip3 install mlxtend --user` if you already have installed it you may need to upgrade it `pip3 install mlxtend --upgrade`